# How to display django success message in every template from one view?

Tags: django, django-views

Here I have one function for `newsletter` which will be used in every template in the project.The issue here is the success message is  displaying only in the contact page template.I have placed django message tag `{{message}}` in the `base.html` only.It is working fine in the `contact.html` page.The corresponding message  for contact and newsletter displays correctly in the `contact_page` template but not in other templates .Other templates also extends `base.html` like the `contact.html`.

How  can i display newsletter success message in every template.I don't want to write `{{message}}` in every template. Is there any solution  for this ?

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your message has been sent successfully.')
            return redirect('contact:contact_page')
    return render(request, 'contact/contact_page.html', {'form': form})


def newsletter(request):
    form = NewsletterForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewsletterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Thank you for your subscription.')
            return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'news_form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

create base.html with links to stylesheet and js files only. There you can place

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

just above the block content, and extend all other templates from it. So it will be better to make a `home.html` file and render the news letter to there, and extend it from `base.html`. Refer [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#message-tags)